# OAuth 2 spring Webclient for password grant

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, reactive-programming, webclient

In the Rest template I was able to to do the following. I'm trying to implement the same using spring webclient and so far I couldn't find any documentation on how to set this  up.

```
@Bean
public OAuth2RestTemplate createRestTemplate() {
    ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resource = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
    resource.setAccessTokenUri(accessTokenUri);
    resource.setClientId(clientID);
    resource.setClientSecret(clientSecret);

    resource.setGrantType("password");
    resource.setScope(Arrays.asList(scope));

    resource.setUsername("user");
    resource.setPassword("pass");


    return new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource);
}
```

Comment: Check out this tutorial on Webclient. What I know about Oauth2 is that clientId and clientSecret will be sent as part of the header, while the remaining will be sent as part of the message body.

Comment: please share the link to the tutorial @Olantobi